# What is the unit of measurement that google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeSignedArea() returns?

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I want to calculate the area in square kilometers of a polygon in Google Maps API V3.
With the google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeSignedArea() this should be possible and easy.

http://code.google.com/intl/en-US/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html#spherical

It works nicely and it returns a number as described in the documentation. But what unit of measurement is the number? I can't find it anywhere! Is it meters, centimeters, feet?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function returns the unit in m^2   (square meters)

As described in the [documentation for computeArea](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/geometry#spherical.computeArea):

> Returns the area of a closed path. The computed area uses the same units as the radius. **The radius defaults to the Earth's radius in meters, in which case the area is in square meters.**